# Was David aware that his words were prophetic according to any doctrines, traditions, or exegesis?

Tags: prophecy, david

Often times Christians cite some of the writings of David as prophetically applicable towards Jesus.

Therefore, I'm curious if there are any doctrines, traditions or textual evidence that suggest that David was or wasn't aware of the prophetic applicability of his writings.

For example:

> "Kiss his son, or he will be angry and your way will lead to your destruction, for his wrath can flare up in a moment. Blessed are all who take refuge in him." - Psalms 2:12

Did David just think he was talking about himself as the anointed son of the Lord or did he recognize a double meaning to come?

The answer to this question could give insight into David's motivations as well as reveal implications for analyzing the writings of other potential or confirmed prophets.

Comment: Footnote here [John 11:50](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+11%3A50&version=RSVCE) says Caiaphas was unaware he was prophesying. I would say Only God knows for sure.

Comment: Since the site doesn't allow opinion-based questions, I have to ask what would be considered a definitive answer on this.  Since Scripture doesn't record David as saying "these words are prophetic" or anything anywhere near that, what would be an acceptable well-sourced answer?  BTW, I'd remove this objection to the question if you were to edit the title to be in-line with the question as far as asking for doctrinal stances.

Comment: Psalm 2:12 says, "Embrace discipline," not "kiss the son." *Bar* (purity, chastity) is "son" only in Aramaic, and without the definite article in this verse. Coincidentally, the Greek Old Testament has embrace *paideia* (discipline, chastizement), which also looks like the word for sons or children (*paidia*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one could know for sure what David knew or was thinking when he wrote, for example, Psalms 22 (one of my favorite) which can clearly be taken as entirely prophetic of Christ, but also refects David's own personal experiences. Jesus quoted (part of) verse one from the cross, "My God, my God, why hast thou forsaken me?", and the soldiers fulfilled verse 18, "They parted my garments..." (having no idea that they were doing so) indicating that it was indeed prophetic.

Ps 49:15 "But God will redeem my soul from the power of the grave: for he will recieve me" shows a little that David did know for sure, and trust in, and again it was Jesus who redeemed David's soul.

Saul also prophesied in I Sam 10:11-12 and in 1 Sam 19:24, and in Num 22 God even opened the mouth of a donkey! 2 Pet 2:16

One thought is that David's own experiences as a rejected king for so many years allowed him to experience some of the same emotions and feelings that Jesus would eventually feel, giving him a personal insight into the Christ that hadn't come yet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe David would have been experienced enough to know when he is under the Spirit of inspiration. However, I'm not aware of any verse of him stating this directly, but then again, neither do most of God's prophet and apostles.

However, it is not just Christians who quote David as prophetically applicable towards Jesus.

Jesus did so Himself and even described David as being in the Spirit.

Matthew 22:

> 43 He said to them, “How then does David in the Spirit call Him ‘Lord,’ saying:
>
> 44 ‘The Lord said to my Lord,
>   “Sit at My right hand,
>   Till I make Your enemies Your footstool”’?[Psalm 110:1]
>
> 45 If David then calls Him ‘Lord,’ how is He his Son?” 46 And no one was able to answer Him a word, nor from that day on did anyone dare question Him anymore.